# Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've honestly looked everywhere for a fix to this error, People have had similar problems but I can't find any that help me fix mine. I am trying to view another users profile page while being signed in as a different user. No Device, for this. I keep running into the same error that looks exactly like this. 
[image]

This is my users_controller.rb,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  after_action :signed_in_after_register, only: :create 

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def dashboard 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end 

  def newsfeed
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == nil
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

  def nav
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def posts
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def welcome
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
    @posts = @user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @comment = Comment.new 
    @post = Post.new 
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @post = Post.new(params[:post_id])
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully created!' }
        format.json { render :profile, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :profile, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def signed_in_after_register 
      session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :bio, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :age, :profile_picture, :post, :body)
    end
   end
```

This is my user model user.rb,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
    validates_inclusion_of :age, in: 10..100
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }, allow_nil: true
    has_many :posts
    has_attached_file :profile_picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
    :default_url => "app/assets/images/missing.png", 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename" 
    validates_attachment_content_type :profile_picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

This is my routes.rb,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#welcome'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#login', :as => :login 

  get 'dashboard' => 'users#dashboard', :as => :dashboard

  post 'logging/user' => 'sessions#create'  

  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout 

  get 'about' => 'about'

  get 'newsfeed' => 'users#newsfeed'

  resources :users, except: :show
  get 'profile/:user_id' => 'users#show', as: :profile

  resources  :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  get 'index' => 'posts#index'

  get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => :register

end
```

And I'm willing to post any code you may need to see to further help me with my problem. Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for 3 weeks now. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: For which page you are getting this error?

Comment: I am getting it on the show page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is looking for "id" prior to hitting your action code, via..

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

..which in turn is calling the "set_user" method and attempts...

```
User.find(params[:id])
```

However, your route defines the parameter as ":user_id", not ":id"...

```
 get 'profile/:user_id' => 'users#show', as: :profile
```

Since you're writing your own .find query in your action, try removing ":show" from your before_action. Or alternatively you could DRY up a bit and just use ":id" everywhere to avoid confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I see here you are providing a field user_id in Params instead of id .you should send the id in the url itself.

> ex: localhost:3000/user/12

Also inside your controller action use params[:id] instead of params[:user_id]

Comment: Is there a way to run it like this? Cause that would be great.
localhost:3000/profile/12

Comment: Then you have to override the default route and add on : member to that .